# Unwanted 'email' displayed using Validation Error for Password Reset Form

Tags: python, django

I'm working on implementing password reset functionality in Django. I wanted to create my own message to the user using the ValidationError class, and I succeeded in doing so. However, unfortunately, an unwanted 'email' is displayed along with this message.

forms.py:

```
class ResetPasswordForm(PasswordResetForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ResetPasswordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=255, label='E-mail Address', required=True,
                             validators=[ValidationError],
                             widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                 'id': 'register-email',
                                 'label': 'required',
                                 'type': 'text',
                                 'placeholder': 'Your E-mail Address'
                             }))

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if not User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email, is_active=True).exists():
            raise ValidationError(f"This address e-mail doesn't exists.")

        return email
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uzQt.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCk8t.png)

views.py

```
def reset_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        reset_form = ResetPasswordForm(data=request.POST)

        if reset_form.is_valid():
            email = reset_form.cleaned_data['email']
            user_email = User.objects.filter(Q(email=email))

            if user_email.exists():
                for user in user_email:
                    parameters = {
                        'email': user_email,
                        'domain': get_current_site(request=request),
                        'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(s=force_bytes(s=user.pk)),
                        'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user=user),
                        'protocol': 'http'
                    }

                    html_message = render_to_string(
                        template_name='accounts/password_reset_email.html',
                        context=parameters
                    )

                    try:
                        messages.success(request=request,
                                         message=f"An email with password reset instructions has been sent "
                                                 f"to your email address {email}.")
                        messages.warning(request=request, message='Your activation link will expire after two days.')
                        send_mail(
                            subject='Reset your Password',
                            message=html_message,
                            from_email=os.environ.get('EMAIL_LOGIN'),
                            recipient_list=[email],
                            fail_silently=False
                        )
                    except ConnectionError:
                        HttpResponse('Invalid Header')

                    return redirect(to='index')

    else:
        reset_form = ResetPasswordForm()

    return render(request=request, template_name='accounts/reset-password.html', context={
        'title': 'Reset Password',
        'reset_form': reset_form
    })
```

HTML:

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div id="user-form">
    <form class="login-form" method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <label>{{ reset_form.email.label }}</label>
                {{ reset_form.email }} {{ reset_form.errors }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="submit-row">
            <button class="btn" type="submit">Send E-mail</button>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

How can I remove it? This knowledge will definitely come in handy in the future.